# Using chi-squared test for feature selection

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, chi-squared

I always have trouble understanding the significance of chi-squared test and how to use it for feature selection. I tried reading the wiki page but I didn't get a practical understanding. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Do you understand the chi-squared test in general? For feature selection it's looking for deviations from observations predicted by the null hypothesis that feature distribution is not dependent on class.

Comment: you should try asking it at http://stats.stackexchange.com/ instead

Answer (score 0):

chi-squared test helps you to determine the most significant features among a list of available features by determining the correlation between feature variables and the target variable.

Example below is taken from https://chrisalbon.com/machine-learning/chi-squared_for_feature_selection.html

The below test will select two best features (since we are assigning 2 to the "k" parameter) among the 4 available features initially.

```
# Load libraries
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2

# Load iris data
iris = load_iris()

# Create features and target
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

# Convert to categorical data by converting data to integers
X = X.astype(int)

# Select two features with highest chi-squared statistics
chi2_selector = SelectKBest(chi2, k=2)
X_kbest = chi2_selector.fit_transform(X, y)
type(X_kbest)

# Show results
print('Original number of features:', X.shape[1])
print('Reduced number of features:', X_kbest.shape[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Chi-squared feature selection is a uni-variate feature selection technique for categorical variables. It can also be used for continuous variable, but the continuous variable needs to be categorized first.

How it works?

It tests the null hypothesis that the outcome class depends on the categorical variable by calculating chi-squared statistics based on contingency table. For more details on contingency table and chi-squared test check the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=misMgRRV3jQ

To categorize the continuous data, there are range of techniques available from simplistic frequency based binning to advance approaches such as Minimum Description Length and entropy based binning methods.

Advantage of using chi-squared test on continuous variable is that it can capture the non-linear relation with outcome variable.